# hint on stokes' theorem problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

In my notes, I've just covered Stokes' theorem and so I expect the problem below to use this... but I'm just not seeing the connection. I would like a hint.

I want to compute $\iint_{S_1\cup S_2} \text{curl}F\cdot dS$ where $S_1=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2=1, 0\le z \le 1\}$ and $S_2=\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2 +(z-1)^2 =1, z\ge 1\}$ and $F(x,y,z)=(zx+z^2y+x,z^2yx+y,z^4x^2)$.

I'm supposed to compute the union of these two surfaces and Stokes theorem (the "calc 3 version") is equipped to compute a surface when that surface is bounded by a loop.  I guess I'm not seeing the loop.

Is this the approach I want to even use.... finding the boundary of a surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boundary of $S_1\cup S_2$ is just $C = \{(x,y,z)\,|\,x^2+y^2=1,z=0\}$. Thus, if $D = \{(x,y,z)\,|\,x^2+y^2\leq1,z=0\}$, we have
$$\iint_{S_1\cup S_2} \nabla \times F \,dS = \int_C F \,d\ell = \iint_D \nabla \times F \, dS$$
Given that the $D$ lies on the $xy$-plane, that last integral should be straightforward. This works because $C$ is the boundary of both $S_1 \cup S_2$ and $D$.

Comment: So this is basically a thimble and I'm integrating its boundary which is the unit circle at $z=0$.  Thanks! That makes sense.

Comment: Yep, you've got the idea.

Comment: Now.... I'm curious why did you do the last integral when you can evaluate the middle one the way that I did in Perez's comments?

Comment: You can do whichever one you'd find easier. For this particular problem, you probably want to go with the line integral, since it happens to be easy. In other cases, the rightmost integral might be easier, since it's essentially a surface integral in two dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $S_1$ is a cylinder centered at the origin and $S_2$ is half of a sphere translated upward along the $z$ axis by one unit, you can see that the sphere forms a cap for the cylinder, and the loop is the bottom of the cylinder, or a circle parametrized by $(\cos t, \sin t, 0)$

Now your integral becomes

$$\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos t,\sin t,0)\cdot (-\sin t, \cos t, 0) \mathrm{d}t=0$$

Comment: I just wanted a hint not a solution.

Comment: also this isn't quite right.  You should have $\int_0^{2\pi} F((\cos t,\sin t,0))\cdot (-\sin t,\cos t, 0) dt$

Comment: @Clclstdnt isn't that exactly what I wrote?

Comment: No.  You have to include $F$.  So after you include $F$, so this should be $F(r(t))\cdot r'(t)= (0*\cos t + 0^2\sin t + \cos t, 0^2\sin t \cos t+\sin t, 0^4\cos^2t)\cdot (-\sin t,\cos t,0) dt = $. Darn it...... it's one of those weird ones, $F$ doesn't change the form so that $\int_0^{2\pi} F(r(t))\cdot r'(t)dt = \int_0^{2\pi} r(t)\cdot r'(t) dt$ ....  I just naively thought you forgot the $F$, it doesn't make a difference here